# Проблема с Pymem. Или какие вообще есть способы подключиться к модулю (dll) процесса в Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для тренировки решил попробовать написать простейший чит. Т.к. по читам для CS:GO очень много гайдов, то выбор пал именно на неё.

Пробую подключиться к DLL для модификации памяти процесса. В гугле нашёл этот код:

```
pm = pymem.Pymem("csgo.exe")
client = client = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_id, "client_panorama.dll")
```

Но client присваивается значение None, тогда как у всех остальных всё работает. Возможно причина в том, что процесс 32 бита, а питон - 64?

Какие вообще есть способы найти адрес DLL процесса силами питона?

Версия Python - 3.6, система - Windows 10 x64, версия pymem - самая последняя из pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не могу сказать про pymem, никогда им не пользовался, но знаю, что память другого процесса можно модифицировать с помощью [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

**memchange.py**

```
import sys
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes


PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

kernel32.OpenProcess.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.OpenProcess.argtypes = [
    wintypes.DWORD,
    wintypes.BOOL,
    wintypes.DWORD
]

kernel32.CloseHandle.restype = wintypes.BOOL
kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = [ wintypes.HANDLE ]

kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.restype = wintypes.BOOL
kernel32.WriteProcessMemory.argtypes = [ 
    wintypes.HANDLE,
    wintypes.LPVOID,
    wintypes.LPCVOID,
    ctypes.c_size_t,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)
]


pid = int(sys.argv[1])
addr = int(sys.argv[2], 16)

val = 42
buf = (val).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')
buf_ptr = ctypes.c_char_p(buf)

ph = kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(ph, addr, buf_ptr, len(buf), None)
kernel32.CloseHandle(ph)
```

Для краткости из кода выброшены все проверки.